# Behavior of echo with many backslashes

Tags: shell, unix

I have a project with the goal of implementing the same behavior as the echo command.  My problem is with backslashes.  My information says that when a backslash appears you must considering the next character as a simple character, but here I guess it's not the same.

This an example :

```
echo \\\\
OUTPUT : \
```

The problem here is that I expect that the output to be 2 backslashes, not just one.
To get 2 backslashes I need to write 6 backslashes:

```
echo \\\\\\
```

Can anyone help me to understand this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple layers where the backslashes are interpreted. It is an escape character in the shell(among other places). A backslash followed by a character is an escape code for another character(for instance, `\n` is interpreted as a line break).

When you first execute `echo \\\\\\`, the shell parses the escape sequences and ends up passing `\\\` to the command(in this case echo).

Quoting the string on the shell will prevent interpretation there(i.e. `echo "\\"` will literally pass two backslashes to the echo command). You also either have an additional layer of interpretation or your program is incorrectly handling the backslash sequence. Ultimately, you'll need to escape it for each layer.